# How to implement a textbox with a clear button in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, textbox

I have the following `UserControl`. It's a `TextBox` with a `Button`:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="0"
        Text="{Binding Text, 
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, 
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         x:Name="TextBox" />

     <Button
         Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=TextBox}"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
         Visibility="{Binding IsClearButtonVisible,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                      Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
         Command="{Binding ClearTextCommand,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"    
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >

         <Button.Content>
             <Image
                 Source="{StaticResource Delete2}"
                 Stretch="None"
                 RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

In Windows 7 it looks great but in Windows XP I have the following issue:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix the issue? If I make the background transparent then there is no problem with the button but the text gets below the button and looks weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the `Button` smaller and/or add a small margin to "downsize" the visible background.

Edit: While looking around a bit (wondering that this hasn't been added as some new Feature) I've found [this article with step-by-step instructions you could give a try](http://davidowens.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/wpf-search-text-box/).

Comment: If I do that then on W7 the button is smaller than the textbox and when you hoover / click on it looks ugly too :(

Comment: Try the blog post I've linked.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchFilter" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200"  
                                 Text="{Binding SearchItemString}" />
<Button Margin="-20,10,5,0" Width="25" Height="25" Content="X" 
                        Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}" />
```

Here is the Style.

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Pretty quick and dirty... thanks.  You could even add right-padding to the TextBox equal to the amount of the button width so your text doesn't go underneath the button.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `ControlTemplate`s here, as example you can see [Search Text Box Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101975/Building-a-Search-Text-Box-Control-with-WPF)
and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can find textbox template